# Proving that $s_n= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^j$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to prove that  the sequence $s_n= \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^j$ is a Cauchy sequence. I started by assuming without loss of generality that $n>m$. Then
\begin{align*}
|s_n-s_m| = \left|\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^j-\sum_{j=1}^m \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^j\right|= \left|\sum_{j=m+1}^n \left(\frac{1}{j}\right)^j\right| = \dots \ ?
\end{align*}
But I don't know if this makes any sense, because I don't know how to continue... I would be really greatful for tips! Thank you!

Comment: Just prove that it converges...

Comment: $(\frac  1 j )^{j} \leq (\frac 1 j )^{2}$ for $j \geq 1$.

Answer (score 6):

You have, for every $j \geq 1$,
$$\frac{1}{j^j} \leq \frac{1}{j^2}$$

Because $\sum \frac{1}{j^2}$ converges, then by comparison,
$$\sum \frac{1}{j^j}$$

also converges, hence the sequence
$$\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j^j}$$

is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I think it's better to compare $\frac{1}{j^j} < \frac{1}{2^j}$. You get a nicer series, and one that can be shown to converge using simple high school math. It's likely that OP doesn't yet know a lot about series.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @5xum I agree with you ! But then, the inequality would be true only for $j\geq 2$... ;)